# Wrapping Text Around Image Using Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

With regard to Bootstrap 4:

Consider the following HTML/CSS code which is currently not responsive (there are currently no Bootstrap "col-". The Lorem Ipsum word wraps the image on the right side, as well as below the image, as a result of the float-left.

```html
<img class="pr-3 pb-3 float-left" src="~/Images/some_image.png" />
        
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
Quisque nisl arcu, tempor a purus quis, congue rutrum libero. 
Suspendisse potenti. 
Aliquam nibh massa, tristique quis sodales at, fermentum at ex. 
Integer nec elementum nibh. 
Sed porta, diam id iaculis vestibulum, nunc nisi venenatis mauris. 
In euismod enim mi ut purus. Morbi ac quam lectus. 
</p>
<p>
Ut dictum, purus ac facilisis eleifend, magna nibh scelerisque elit. 
In pellentesque dui turpis ut quam. 
Praesent ullamcorper eros at lectus elementum tempus. 
Donec fermentum velit nec fermentum bibendum. 
In sit amet aliquam nulla, at vestibulum ligula. 
Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. 
Nam lacus purus, interdum nec blandit vel, lacinia ac ex.
</p>
```

I am unsure what Bootstrap syntax to use to *keep the word wrap in place* at the "md" breakpoint, and then at "sm" breakpoint goto "col-12" on the image, and "col-12" on the text, placing the text below the image, vice the current word wrap.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think it is possible to transition an element from float to col, responsively. But you can responsively show and hide one of each

```
<img class="pr-3 pb-3 float-left d-none d-md-block" src="~/Images/some_image.png" />
<img class="pb-3 col-12 d-md-none" src="~/Images/some_image.png" />
```

The `.float-left` is initially hidden at xs with `.d-none` then shown from md up with `.d-md-block`, while the `.col-12` is hidden for md up with `.d-md-none`

Answer (score 0):

BS4 has responsive floats. So if you set `float-left-md` on the image it should help.
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/float/#responsive

Example:

```
<img class="pr-md-3 pb-3 float-md-left img-fluid" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" />
```

https://codepen.io/crishpeen/pen/PgxELO

Comment: I reworded the question... I don't think my verbiage was clear.  Using Bootstrap 4 I want to word wrap the image at the "md" breakponit, and at the "sm" breakpoint I want to go "col-12" on both to put the text below the picture...

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with `css` as well. Remove the `float-left` from the `html` in your `img` class and then add this to your css:

```
img {
  float: left;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 540px) {
  img {
    float: none
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this It will word wrap the image at the "md" breakponit and at the "sm" breakpoint It will put the text below the image.

```html
<html> 
<head>
  <title>Wrapping Text Around Image</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
  <style type="text/css">
    .pb-3 {
        padding-bottom: 0 !important;
    }
    /* Small devices (landscape phones, 576px and up) */
    @media (min-width: 576px) { 
      .float-md-left {
          float: none !important;
      }
    }
    /* Medium devices (tablets, 768px and up) */
    @media (min-width: 768px) { 
      .float-md-left {
          float: none !important;
      }
    }
    /* Large devices (desktops, 992px and up) */
    @media (min-width: 992px) { 
      .float-md-left {
          float: left !important;
      }
    }
    /* Extra large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up) */
    @media (min-width: 1200px) {
      .float-md-left {
          float: left !important;
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
    <img class="pr-3 pb-3 float-md-left" src="https://via.placeholder.com/140x100" />
    <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
    Quisque nisl arcu, tempor a purus quis, congue rutrum libero. 
    Suspendisse potenti. 
    Aliquam nibh massa, tristique quis sodales at, fermentum at ex. 
    Integer nec elementum nibh. 
    Sed porta, diam id iaculis vestibulum, nunc nisi venenatis mauris. 
    In euismod enim mi ut purus. Morbi ac quam lectus. 
    </p>
    <p>
    Ut dictum, purus ac facilisis eleifend, magna nibh scelerisque elit. 
    In pellentesque dui turpis ut quam. 
    Praesent ullamcorper eros at lectus elementum tempus. 
    Donec fermentum velit nec fermentum bibendum. 
    In sit amet aliquam nulla, at vestibulum ligula. 
    Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. 
    Nam lacus purus, interdum nec blandit vel, lacinia ac ex.
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```